# Is there any use for a isTrue-function?

Tags: python, function

```
def istrue(a):
    if a:
        return True
    return False
```

Can such a function have its niche somehow?
I mean if I want to check the trueness of a variable I can always just use

```
if variable:
   do that
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're correct, it's pointless.

Comment: This exists. It's `bool`.

Comment: Are you looking for a problem to be solved by your solution?

Comment: @zvone basicly yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, defining a function like this:

```
def istrue(a):
    if a:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and using it like this:

```
value = True
if istrue(value):
     print('True!')
```

would be no different than this:

```
if bool(value):
    print('True!')
```

or this:

```
if value:
    print('True!')
```

Therefore abstracting that boolean evaluation into a function wouldn't do anything. However, there could be a use case for determining whether or not `a` is an instance of a boolean along with doing the boolean evaluation of `a` to determine if it is a literal `True`. But even that I wouldn't abstract into a function, I would write it like this:

```
if value is True:
    print('True!')
```

Comment: Of course you wouldn't abstract it into a function: you'd have to then check the return value of the function. Plus there's always `isinstance(x, bool)`. Either way +1

Comment: @MadPhysicist If the function did the evaluation then you would not have to check the return value of the function, that would be redundant

Comment: Evaluating something in a vacuum is pointless. The function would have to direct you to do something based on that evaluation, which means that you have to check its return value in the caller.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for non-zero values for example since True and False just is a glorified 0 or non 0, it can also check if a string is containing anything ""=False, "something"=True, the same goes for other arrays

Comment: i could imagine that if you were doing alot of checks in a code simply writing bool(a) would be more convenient than writing a whole if statement. Well that just my 2 cent anyways :)

Comment: Yes, this depends on the particular use case.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can pass a function as a parameter to another function. Your `istrue` could be passed in this manner.

```
def myfilter(seq, func):
    for x in seq:
        if func(x):
            yield x

print(list(myfilter([0,1,2,3], istrue)))
```

Realize that this is a toy example and a non-trivial use case would be more useful but more complicated.

As pointed out in the comments, there's no need to write your own `istrue` function because Python already has one: `bool`.

Comment: +1. This is a good point but I think it depends on the use case. In your example, where you use it once, I would simply use a lambda function like `lambda x: bool(x)` in place of `istrue`.

Comment: @Cole yes this would be the perfect place for a lambda, unless it was something you were doing often. Or you just wanted better code readability.

Comment: now that I think of it more, the `lambda` statement itself is pointless since we can use `bool` in place of `istrue` instead since it's callable.

Comment: That's much more complicated than just using `None` for the function.

Comment: @MadPhysicist and how would you call `None` as a function?

Comment: Have you looked at the built in filter? If you don't like none, use bool.

Comment: @MadPhysicist sorry I forgot that Python has its own built-in `filter` function. I renamed it just for you. I wish I could think of a more realistic example.

Comment: My point is that every incarnation of this function already exists in the language. There's not much market for inefficient redundancy.

Comment: @MadPhysicist and *my* point is that there are times when you want to pass a function into another function, and that there might be legitimate reasons to use `bool` as the function to pass in. My imagination is just failing me when coming up with a relevant example. Don't take `myfilter` literally.